# How to display Missing Search box in List view in SharePoint-2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, list-view-web-part, list-search-box

I am using SharePoint 2013 Foundation. I have created a page and kept a list view of custom list.

My requirement is to display the default list view search box.

[image]

But when I keep the list view on the page it does not show any search box to search the items in the current list.

I have already checked the option **Display search box** from the web part edit menu.

How can I display search box?

**NOte:** I have already gone through [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216260/search-box-missing) post. There question is related to library and there "Display search box" is missing. Mine case is different.

[image]

Comment: The seach box is dependent on the style you are using for the view. Are you using the default style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SharePoint foundation you won't see"Find an item" search box as this feature is limited to Enterprise version.

Comment: Seems correct. Can you share any documentation reference?

Comment: It's hard to find the official document stating it now, i happen to know this fact as i had ran into same issue sometime back.

Answer (score 0):

Under Modify View of the impacted SharePoint list, click the + sign to expand the Style options and make sure the View Style is set to the Default. The other options remove the Search bar. [image]